# Phonegap 3.4- Plugin installed but cannot see the Java file for that specific plugin in my src folder

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am new to phoneGap app development and its getting over my head now. I installed a plugin successfully and if I navigate to the folder (from windows) I can find the plugin but in my Eclipse, I cannot see the package and java file for that Specific plugin. I installed the plugin by foloowing this official documentation:
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/466

Also, I want to know in which of the `config.xml` file should I add the following line as mentioned in the documentation:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.plugin.datepicker" version="0.3.2" />
```

as I see two config.xml files in my project , First in the root project folder and second in the assets->www->config.xml. To my understanding, the one in the root folder is for all the platforms and the one in assets->www folder is platform specific (android in my case). Please help.

FYI this is a third party plugin.

Answer (score 1):

That documentation is for using the PhoneGap Build online service.

To install plugins locally (for use in Eclipse) you need to have the `cordova` CLI installed and use `cordova plugin add http://github.com/nicholasareed/cordova-plugin-datepicker.git` then run `cordova build`

Comment: But I executed this command using phonegap CLI and if I list the plugins I can see the plugin is successfully installed. But I am not able to use that.

Comment: did you run `cordova build` after installing?

Comment: I ran 'phonegap build android' and the build was successful. But still the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried any other date picker plugins? This one has real good documentation: https://github.com/kdileep1990/com.dileep.plugins.datepicker/tree/3aeac69af2a7fdf14b2c1f6e060d7f8706728cf2

Comment: Yes I tried using this. and In its documentation it says that it is supported for phonegap 3.4 but when I try to insall this plugin it says that it requires version 2.9